# Beginner flex question: Using external MXML and states (and calling functions of parent)

Tags: apache-flex, mxml, flash-builder

Relatively new to Flex/FlashBuilder and am currently trying to make an Android AIR app. I'm currently struggling to use external MXML files for each page and opening them by calling states.

The way I'm planning it is to call a function on buttonClicks which is housed in the main MXML file.

The thing is, how do I call this function? When I try using:

```
<s:Button id="b1" label="Change to State 1" click="Main.goHome()'"/>
```

Although this throws up an error.

Is this the best approach to take first of all? And second of all, how can I access the main function? It seems somewhat different to ActionScript in that sense!

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
 click="parentApplication.goHome()"
```

or

```
 click="parentDocument.goHome()"
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try Adnan's method; though for a more general principle I might suggest passing a reference of Main into the class you are trying to access it from.